# Laravel 4 subdomain routing on VPS/WHM

Tags: laravel-4

I have been trying to get Laravel 4 subdomain routing to work for a couple of hours now and I just cannot seem to figure it out. I have a VPS and I'm fairly new to a lot of VPS concepts.

The domain in question is an account on the VPS - the main domain of the VPS is different. So, main domain is `example.com` and the account I am trying to get subdomain routing working on is `foobar.com` - a cPanel account on `example.com`

I put the following above the document root route on foobar.com's Routes file -

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.foobar.com'), function()
{

    Route::get('/', function($account, $id)
    {
        echo $account;
    });

});
```

I was expecting this to output the subdomain entered - for example `something.foobar.com` would echo `something`. Instead I get `Error code: ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED`.

Since this is a cPanel account, I tried adding a subdomain in cPanel. This of course creates a directory of the same name as the subdomain in public_html, which is the doc root for that subdomain. When I navigate to the subdomain after adding it in cPanel, it says cannot list the directory.. blah blah.. basically it's an empty directory and the server will not show anything. If I attempt to delete the directory in public_html, I get a generic 500 error.

Clearly I'm missing something, the Laravel documentation either falls short or this type of server configuration requires something else. Help please! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woohoo! I got it working after a little more reading.

I had to log in as root to my VPS WHM control panel and add a wildcard A DNS entry (*) for the domain. Then I modified `/etc/httpd.conf` and modified the line ServerAlias to `*.foobar.com foobar.com`. Restarted httpd and viola!

This is awesome!

Comment: I was reproducing this in my local environment. Don't forget to update your /etc/hosts file or DNS depending on your environment.